# Using action attribute to connect JS script to a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner here. Everyone starts somewhere. Hoping someone can help me understand this.

I'm trying to create a simple page that takes in an input and creates a profile based on the input.

I have two HTML files. One that accepts input, `sign-up.html`, and one that outputs the profile, on `profile.html`.

There is also one JS script, in `script.js`, that includes the following code:

```
//Information from Form
    //Username
    let profileName = document.getElementById("name").innerText;
    //Profile Picture
    let imageSrc = document.getElementById("profilePic").src;
    //Email
    let email = document.getElementById("inputEmail").innerText;
    //Bio
    let bio = document.getElementById("bio").innerText;

    //Submit button
    const body = document.getElementById("profilePage");

//HTML locations on profile.html
const userNameLocation = document.getElementById("username-goes-here");
const emailLocation = document.getElementById("email-goes-here");
const imageLocation = document.getElementById("image-goes-here");
const bioLocation = document.getElementById("bio-goes-here");

const submission = () => {
    userNameLocation.innerText = profileName;
    imageLocation.src = imageSrc;
    emailLocation.innerText = email;
    bioLocation.innerText = bio;
}

body.addEventListener('load', submission());
```

It takes in and creates references to HTML DOM elements, and changes their innerText property to what was inputed on the form in `sign-up.html`.

When I click submit, it goes to `profile.html`, but with the boilerplate text that I originally built it with, not the inputted data from the HTML form on `sign-up.html`:

```
<body id ="profilePage" onload="submission()">
    <div class="profile-main">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2 id="username-goes-here">Title</h2>
                <h4 id="email-goes-here">email@website.com</h4>
                <img src="images/profile.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Profile Thumbnail" width = "200px" id="image-goes-here">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p id="bio-goes-here">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                    Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh. Urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. 
                    Non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam.
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is not what I want. I want the `profile.html` page to reflect the info that has been inputted on the form.I'm not sure how to connect the script logic to the HTML form, then have it load onto `profile.html`. I currently am using the `action` attribute:

```
<form action="profile.html" onsubmit="submission()" method="">
```

[Full Git repo here](https://github.com/solangewright/javascript/tree/main/projects/profile-generator)

Comment: If you submit to an HTML page the entire JS context is lost (that's just how browsers work). You could store the data in local storage/etc, but it's not clear what your end goal is--normally this type of information would be stored in a back-end system/DB.

Comment: Ok, interesting. Any beginner recommendations on how I should go about this? Self-learner here

Comment: @solo1999 — Find an introductory tutorial for server side programming in the language of your choice. e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side

Comment: Tutorial/etc recommendations are off-topic on SO. It'd also depend on what **specifically** you're trying to do, and where there are issues.

Comment: I'm guessing I should prob save this in an external database, then run an API request and output that JSON data onto the page?

Comment: My goal is just to practice modifying DOM elements through an HTML form.

Comment: @solo1999 That doesn't require anything on the back end (or even multiple pages). You could halt normal submission and do all the things on a single page if you're only interested in DOM manipulation based on user input.

Comment: @DaveNewton is there a way I can do that and at least have it navigate to a next page?

Comment: @solo1999 Yes, you could save the data to local storage (or other client-side persistence mechanism; local storage is quick and easy).

Comment: If you just wanted to try to pass value through html page and modifiying the `profile.html` with the values without taking web security aspect into the count. Then can you simply do it using `method="GET"` on the `sign-up.html` form and then process the values from the url that send by GET method in `profile.html`.